# What are the rules for writing a sort comparator

Tags: java, scala, sorting, illegalargumentexception

I want to sort the objects of class `A` based on the values of members: `a`, `b` ,`c`: `A` is given the most preference -> `b` is the next -> `c` has the least preference.

Comparator is used by:
`x = x.sortWith(comparator)`
here, x is a ArrayBuffer[A]

```
class A {var a,b,c = 0}

def comparator(f1:A, f2:A) = {
    if(f1.a == f2.a) {
      if(f1.b == f2.b) f1.c > f2.c
      else f1.b > f2.b
    }
    else f1.a > f2.a
  }
```

Using this I am getting:

```
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!**
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sorted(SeqLike.scala:618)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.sorted(Seq.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sortWith(SeqLike.scala:575)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.sortWith(Seq.scala:41)
```

Comment: You return `boolean` result, but it's supposed to be `int`

Comment: Using that I am getting an error: 

Error:(124, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Boolean

Comment: How to you use your `comparator`? Can you post more code?

Comment: Sure! here, x is a ArrayBuffer[A] 
`x = x.sortWith(comparator)`

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier to do with `sortBy` and a tuple:

```
x sortBy {f => (f.a, f.b, f.c)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a more comprehensive test case? This example ran fine for me:

```
class A {var a,b,c = 0}

def comparator(f1:A, f2:A) = {
    if(f1.a == f2.a) {
      if(f1.b == f2.b) f1.c > f2.c
      else f1.b > f2.b
    }
    else f1.a > f2.a
  }

val testList = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[A]

val val1 = new A()
val val2 = new A()
val val3 = new A()

val1.a=1
val1.b=1
val1.c=1

val2.a = 1
val2.b = 1
val2.c = 1

val3.a = 2
val3.b = 2
val3.c = 3

testList += val1 
testList += val2 
testList += val3

testList.sortWith(comparator)
```